# WHERE clause only if value exists

Tags: mysql, wordpress, where-clause

I want to filter some WordPress posts by a custom postmeta. However the postmeta does't exist for all posts. But for those that exist, I want to filter them using this logic `postmeta >= date( 'Ymd', strtotime( 'today' ) )`.

My code will be using the `posts_clauses` filter, and I've already added a join clause like this:

```
$posts_clauses['join'] .= " LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta meta ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = meta.post_id AND meta.meta_key = 'my_custom_date') ";
```

So I tried to use a where clause like this:

```
$posts_clauses['where'] .= " AND meta.meta_value >= " . date( 'Ymd', strtotime( 'today' ) );
```

But it then shows only posts that have a `my_custom_date` postmeta, which is also larger than today in Ymd format...

Any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: do `AND (meta.meta_value >= ... OR meta.meta_id IS NULL)`

Comment: Let me check and I'll report back!

Comment: @ysth this worked great! Thanks a million. Could you also help me with the correct arguements for the same problem but when working with the WP_query? I did it like this:     `$query_args['meta_query'][] = array(
        'key'     => 'my_custom_date',
        'value'   => date( 'Ymd', strtotime( 'today' ) ),
        'compare' => '>=',
    );`

and in fact it worked, but I hadn't noticed that it returns only results where my_custom_date is set...

Comment: I don't know much about WP_query, but maybe something like `array( 'relation' => 'OR', array( 'key' => 'my_custom_date', 'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS' ), array( 'key' => 'my_custom_date', 'compare' => '>=', 'value' => date( 'Ymd', strtotime( 'today' ) ) ) )`

Comment: Yup, I found it too, and was coming here to let you know! Indeed that's the solution! Wonder  what you'd do if you knew WP better! :D Thanks a million!